# Slim Framework, Rest Api routes structure in folders need to call options for each API

Tags: cors, slim

I have developed an Api that runs routes on folders instead of single file for all routes(as some people does), before modifing Api structure I need to find out why I need to call Options every time I call a different API, I already understand the CORS concept and it is working on my server/clientbut don´t understand why call options, is it normal or do I have to map all routes in a single file? if this is the case does it affects to have all routes mapped on a single call or is the better way to have separated apis on diferent folders?

This is the way I do it in slim, all calls for the api "users" are included in "document_root -> v2 -> users -> index.php", inside index.php I call the SlimFramework Engine and as well Api Calls like this:

```
users api called at: api.host.com/v2/users/
GET host.com/v2/users/ = document_root -> v2-> users -> read.php
POST host.com/v2/users/ = document_root -> v2-> users -> add.php
PUT host.com/v2/users/ = document_root -> v2-> users -> edit.php
```

in index.php:

```
// read
$app->get('/', function () use ($api) {
    include 'read.php';
});
// add
$app->post('/', function () use ($api) {
    include 'add.php';
});
// update
$app->put('/', function () use ($api) {
    include 'edit.php';
});
and so on...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Preflight requests e.g. `OPTIONS` are part of `CORS` standard. In general preflight request is sent if `CORS` request uses any other request method than `GET`, `HEAD` or `POST`.  Also, if `POST` is used to send request data with a `Content-Type` other than `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, `multipart/form-data`, or `text/plain` then the request is preflighted.

When doing APIs you usually do `application/json` requests which means the requests will be preflighted.